# Is there an example project for monaco-editor with omnisharp on a webpage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor, omnisharp

In my project, I use C# Roslyn scripts for some automation that can my customer write alone. I compile and run this on runtime.

Now I would like to have a web editor for c# with intellisense and spell check. For code completion, I would like also to get some private nugget packets with my API to provide to the script.

Actually, I do that with Visual Studio Code. But it would be nice to have the same behavior on a self-hosted web page.

I have found the Monaco-editor and omnisharp project. I think this is good because Visual Studio Code uses it also.

Does anyone know a sample project or open source project that bring these things together? I am sure I am not the first with this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your needs correctly but here is a young open-source project to bring c# code completion to Monaco
https://github.com/dotnetprojects/MonacoRoslynCompletionProvider